# I wish I were versus I wish I had been

Tags: differences

Is there any difference when I say I wish I were rich or I wish I had been rich?

Comment: Hello, Khan. This level of question is suitable for our sister site, ELL, but as it's your first time here ... Try adding a temporal adverbial. I wish I were rich now / now that I need money for the business venture. I wish I had been rich then / when I was in Paris / in my youth. The use of 'were' in 'I wish I were' is a usage often known as the subjunctive mood (here, the 'volitional subjunctive': I'm not rich, but I really desire to be rich), and is not the same 'were' that occurs in say 'We were poor at that time'.

Comment: *were* is also used in a contra-factual sense. See [ell.se]